# AWS DMS LOB Support (Relational to ES)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I have Full LOB enabled for a DMS migration but still get the following error: `Column 'data_json' is unsupported in table def 'table.users' since the LOB support is disabled`. Is this a bug in DMS or is my configuration incorrect?. The `data_json` column is a text data type.

Note: This migration is from a relational database to Elasticsearch.

Update: Apparently, AWS DMS doesn't support migration of LOB data types from relational tables to ES. If that's the case, any ideas on how to handle collections such as an array of values? Without this feature, DMS is very limiting.

Comment: "Apparently, AWS DMS doesn't support migration of LOB data types from relational tables to ES" is this stated somewhere?

Comment: Any solutions found for this?